# JavaScript use for loop to create p tag with innerHTML content filled in

Tags: javascript, html, dom, for-loop, innerhtml

i am using a for loop to generate paragraph tags based on the length of my `array`. I want each of these p tags generated to have the same `innerHTML`. I can get the tags to generate with the class name but the `innerHTML` remains **blank**.

I have tried the following to no avail, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
for (i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) { 

     var line = document.createElement("p");
     line.className = "line";
     document.body.appendChild(line);

     var b = document.getElementsByClassName("line");
     b.innerHTML = "|";


}
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of elements. You'll need to access an or each `Element` within the collection to assign `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` should return an array of elements, not a single element.  You could try: `getElementsByClassName('line')[i]`, if there is some reason you are doing that specifically.

***Note:** `getElementsByClassName('line')[i]`* *may not refer to the object you just created, unless there are no other "line"s on the page.*  *It scans the document for all elements that have a class called line, which could be paragraphs or other element types.*

---

For a better alternative, please refer to changes made below.  This:

- caches the `numArray` length into a variable, so you are not performing that operation at each loop iteration
- sets the HTML and ClassName of the element you created before attaching it to the document; which has a number of performance benefits
- does not unnecessarily do a DOM lookup for elements, which is expensive
- uses the `var` keyword to avoid scoping conflicts for loop variables

#### [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2uy1etv/):

```
for ( var i=0, n=numArray.length; i < n; i++) { 
  var line = document.createElement("p");
  line.className = "line";
  line.innerHTML = '|';
  document.body.appendChild(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `getElementsByClassName` you can change the innerHTML of `line` since you already have the reference to the DOM element.

```
 for (i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) { 

      var line = document.createElement("p");
      line.className = "line";
      line.innerHTML = "|"; 
      document.body.appendChild(line);

   }
```

And explaining why it didn't work, it's because getElementsByClassName returns a collecion of elements, you need to loop through them.